# Ignore wordpress shortcode when outputting a limited word count

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have created my own custom word limit function in wordpress. I need a way to ignore the shortcode as part of the word count. **I don't want to strip it out** but ignore shortcodes as part of the word count. Otherwise if you choose a number say 15 and the shortcode is in any part of that 15 word limit then the page will fatal error.

```
function my_word_limit($limit) {
    $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
            if (count($content)>=$limit) {
                    array_pop($content);
                    $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
            } else {
                    $content = implode(" ",$content);
            }
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

    return $content;    
}
```

This is the shortcode I would be using for example.

```
[di-video-logged-out]<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LEIu8gba634" width="854" height="480"></iframe>[/di-video-logged-out]
```

Comment: Regardless of ignoring the shortcode, shouldn't you write code that doesn't "fatal error" if/when the parameter is too low?

Comment: An answer is what would help solve the fatal error which is why I wrote the question.

Comment: If that's what you're really asking, then you did not even tell us the exact error message and line number.

Comment: I just want help ignoring the shortcode in the count, the fatal error response should not matter in this instance. I was just stating that was what was happening if the shortcode is not ignored and counted as part of the words. Sorry if I was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

### Trim content and limit with certain count word

*( Keep shortcode on output even content trimmed, you can tweak also if you don't )*

Here my approach with use [`wp_trim_word`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) of the content and filter [`wp_trim_word`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_trim_words/). Also, you can use this function `wpso36236774_trim_words` into such as `$post->post_content` or `get_the_content` directly ( without filter ). Usage was commented inside code.

```
add_filter( 'wp_trim_words', 'wpso36236774_trim_words', 10, 4 );
/* Trims text to a certain number of words.
 * @author Jevuska
 * @version 1.0.1
 *
 * Kepp shortcode if exist in text.
 * Combination function of strip_shortcodes and wp_trim_words
 * Default $num_words = 55
 *
 ** USAGE
 ** Using directly
 ** wpso36236774_trim_words( $text, 56 )
 ** wpso36236774_trim_words( $text, 56, null, false, false, true ) - return array
 ** Shortcode hidden if $num_words is not set or if set with value = 55 with 4 arguments
 **
 ** Use wp_trim_words
 ** wp_trim_words( $text, $num_words = 56 )
 ** Fire wp_trim_words
 ** Shortcode hidden if $num_words is not set or $num_words = 55
 ** Position always in bottom
 ** add_filter( 'wp_trim_words', 'wpso36236774_trim_words', 10, 4 );
 *
 * @param  string  $text             Text to trim.
 * @param  int     $num_words        The number of words to trim the text to. Default 5.
 * @param  string  $more             An optional string to append to the end of the trimmed text, e.g. &hellip;.
 * @param  string  $original_content The text before it was trimmed.
 * @param  mix     $pos              Shortcode Position. You can set 'top' value if using directly
 * @param  boolean $count            Get word count
 * @return string  The text after the filter witch $num_words
 * @return array   If using directly and parameter $count set to true
 */
function wpso36236774_trim_words( $text, $num_words = 55, $more = null, $original_content = false, $pos = false, $count = false )
{
    if ( null === $more)
        $more = ' ' . '[&hellip;]';
    
    $shortcode = $strip_shortcode = true;
    
    if ( ! $original_content )
        $original_content = $text;
    
    $text = $original_content;
    
    /* Check existing shortcode
     *
     */
    if ( false === strpos( $text, '[' ) )
        $strip_shortcode = false;
    
    global $shortcode_tags;
    
    if ( empty( $shortcode_tags ) || ! is_array( $shortcode_tags ) )
        $strip_shortcode = false;
    
    /* Strip content from shortcode
     *
     */
    if ( $strip_shortcode )
    {
        preg_match_all( '@\[([^<>&/\[\]\x00-\x20=]++)@', $text, $matches );
        $tagnames = array_intersect( array_keys( $shortcode_tags ), $matches[1] );
        
        if ( ! empty( $tagnames ) )
        {
            $text = do_shortcodes_in_html_tags( $text, true, $tagnames );
            $pattern = get_shortcode_regex( $tagnames );
            preg_match_all( "/$pattern/", $text, $match );
            if ( ! empty( $match[0] ) && is_array( $match[0] ) )
            {
                $shortcode = '';
                $length    = count( $match[0] );
                for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $length; $i++ )
                    $shortcode .= do_shortcode( $match[0][ $i ] ); //match shortcode
            }
            
            $text = preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/", 'strip_shortcode_tag', $text );
            $text = unescape_invalid_shortcodes( $text );
        }
    }
    
    /* Hide shortcode
     * Base on count function arguments
     *
     */
    if ( func_num_args() == 1 || ( func_num_args() == 4 && 55 == $num_words ) )
         $shortcode = '';
     
    /* Split content into array words
     *
     */
    $text = wp_strip_all_tags( $text );
    
    /*
     * translators: If your word count is based on single characters (e.g. East Asian characters),
     * enter 'characters_excluding_spaces' or 'characters_including_spaces'. Otherwise, enter 'words'.
     * Do not translate into your own language.
     */
    if ( strpos( _x( 'words', 'Word count type. Do not translate!' ), 'characters' ) === 0 && preg_match( '/^utf\-?8$/i', get_option( 'blog_charset' ) ) )
    {
        $text = trim( preg_replace( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", ' ', $text ), ' ' );
        preg_match_all( '/./u', $text, $words_array );
        $limit_words_array = array_slice( $words_array[0], 0, $num_words + 1 );
        $full_words_array  = $words_array[0];
        $sep = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $limit_words_array = preg_split( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $num_words + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
        $full_words_array  = explode( ' ', preg_replace( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", ' ', $text ) );
        $sep = ' ';
    }
    
    /* Check word count base on $num_words
     *
     */
    $word_count = count( $full_words_array );
    if ( $word_count >= $num_words )
    {
        array_pop( $limit_words_array );
        $text  = implode( $sep, $limit_words_array );
        $text .= $more;
        
        /* keep shortcode if exists and set position ( top or bottom text )
         *
         */
        switch( $pos )
        {
            case 'top' :
                $text = $shortcode . $text;
                break;
            
            default :
                $text .= $shortcode;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $original_content );
    }
    
    if ( $count )
        return array(
            'text'  => $text,
            'count' => $word_count
        );
    
    return $text; //output
}
```

Let me know if any issue about this code. Tweak as you need and I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

- Fix multiple shortcode
- Hide shortcode option base on total argument
- Patch `$pos` for additional shortcode position top and bottom text ( func directly only ). For another positon, you must set class and css for your shortcode.

Comment: This is just about perfect, thank-you! Solved the fatal error issue. How would I go about making it so the shortcode does not always appear at the bottom, and also that the shortcode does not show unless it is within the wordcount? I also noticed adding more than one shortcode does not work.

Comment: Awesome works great, the only thing I did not see working though was the "Hide shortcode option based on total argument". Can you make that an option to work or not like you did for the shortcode position? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: total argument mean if you use filter there are 4 argument, and we can't change that. But for use directly if you set only 1 argument like $text only, it mean 1 argument and shortcode hide.Btw is my answer solve your basic issue on question?